# Marker doesn't appear or get overwritten by line

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker, overwrite

Running this code with Sppyder on my desktop displays the markers properly. Using the same code on my laptop and doesn't show them anymore.

I have the same spyder (python 3.7) version. If I invert the line of code and put market before line I can see them, BUT the line get over the marker. What I want it's the marker be over the line.

---

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price in $')

df_MA.iloc[:,0].plot(ax=ax1, color='k', lw=1.)

df_MA[['short_MA', 'long_MA']].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2.)

ax1.plot(df_MA.loc[df_MA.positions == 1.0].index, df_MA.short_MA[df_MA.positions == 1.0],'^', markersize=10, color='g')
         
ax1.plot(df_MA.loc[df_MA.positions == -1.0].index, df_MA.short_MA[df_MA.positions == -1.0], 'v', markersize=10, color='r')

plt.show()
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `Zorder` and put my marker code line in first work.

```py
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price in $')

ax1.plot(df_MA.loc[df_MA.positions == 1.0].index, df_MA.short_MA[df_MA.positions == 1.0],'^', markersize=10, color='g', zorder=2)
         
ax1.plot(df_MA.loc[df_MA.positions == -1.0].index, df_MA.short_MA[df_MA.positions == -1.0], 'v', markersize=10, color='r', zorder=2)

df_MA.iloc[:,0].plot(ax=ax1, color='k', lw=1., zorder=0)

df_MA[['short_MA', 'long_MA']].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2., zorder=1)

plt.show()
```